# Spring boot app "mvn test" command does not find any tests

Tags: spring, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

so the issue i currently have is that running Springboot junit5 tests from IntelliJ works great. Even running a single test with maven by: "mvn -Dtest=CardsControllerTest test" command works.

But when i try to run all tests with "mvn test" i get:

````
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.duliszewski:mtg >-------------------------
[INFO] Building mtg 0.8
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ mtg ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ mtg ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ mtg ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mtg ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ mtg ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.620 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-05T18:55:47+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------```
````

Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtg</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
    <name>mtg</name>
    <description>Simple online mtg cards viewer</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As you can see the tests are not run at all. 
Test methods are annotated with junit @Test jupiter annotation.
Anyone has an idea whats going on?

Project structure:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: First why should surefire run integration tests. It's intended for unit tests. Furthermore how do you have named your test classes and where do you have located them? And why are you defining so many versions of artifact where most of them already handled by spring boot...for example lombok, spring-securitiy-config? etc. and why using an old version of spring boot?

Comment: Using this version of Spring boot should not have such an effect on tests. In case of test names they are named ending with *Test in case of unit tests and *IT in case of integration tests. They are created in packages corresponding to the normal classes. I attached a picture

Comment: First the spring boot version itself usually not but your mixture of different versions can cause issues. Remove whole maven-surefire-plugin part cause maven-surefire-plugin/failsafe already know how to run unit/it tests. Configuration is done by spring boot. Finally which unit test framework do you use? I don't see any dependency for that? JUnit Jupiter Yes but only using that transitivly which I strongly discourage. If you remove the complete maven-surefire-plugin part your tests will run via `mvn clean test`...

Comment: You are picking older versions of spring-security-config if you define that version than spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE already has in...and also older versions of lombok...

Comment: Ok so I removed spring-security-config, and maven-surefire-plugin (btw where i can find this dependency, i can't find it anywhere, I can see failsafe in parent though) and run with mvn clean test and now my unitTests are indeed run, but not my integration tests, of which name ends with "IT". When i renamed one of the tests to end with "Test" it was run though

Comment: Also why should i duplicate JUnit Jupiter dependency if it's already defined in spring-boot-starter-test?